# How to Show 1 plan in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i have a page "deposits" here are plans are availble with the use of "foreach"
now i wnt to show only plan number 3 here. mean plan of  id 3.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($plan as $p)

    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-info panel-pricing">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>{{ $p->name }}</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div style="font-size: 18px;padding: 18px;" class="panel-body text-center">
                <p><strong>{{ $p->minimum }} {{ $basic->currency }} - {{ $p->maximum }} {{ $basic->currency }}</strong></p>
            </div>
            <ul style='font-size: 15px;' class="list-group text-center bold">
                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Commission - {{ $p->percent }} <i class="fa fa-percent"></i> </li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Time - {{ $p->time }} times </li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Compound - <span class="aaaa">{{ $p->compound->name }}</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow: hidden">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon icon-left delete_button"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DelModal"
                            data-id="{{ $p->id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Invest Under This Package
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Then you need an "`if`" nested inside the `foreach`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply extract the plan from your `$plan` collection , does not need loop in below case

```
$p = $plan ->find(3);
```

Comment: Won't that return the 4th item in the collection, instead of the item with id=3 ? :-/

Comment: find will return record against your primary key, in your case it is 3

Comment: what did you try , just paste it

Comment: $p = $plan->(3);

                            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                <div class="panel panel-info panel-pricing">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>{{ $p->name }}</b></h3>
                                    </div>

Comment: <?php $p = $plan->(3);?> <div class="col-sm-4 text-center"> <div class="panel panel-info panel-pricing"> <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>{{ $p->name }}</b></h3> </div>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' (View: C:\xamp\htdocs\assets\core\resources\views\user\bonus-new.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `foreach` and show plan id 3 , then try this :

```
        <div class="row">
     @foreach($plan as $p)
     @if($p == 3)

     <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="panel panel-info panel-pricing">
     <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>{{ $p->name }}</b></h3>
                                            </div>
    <div style="font-size: 18px;padding: 18px;" class="panel-body text-center">
     <p><strong>{{ $p->minimum }} {{ $basic->currency }} - {{ $p->maximum }} {{ $basic->currency }}</strong></p>
                                            </div>
 <ul style='font-size: 15px;' class="list-group text-center bold">
    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Commission - {{ $p->percent }} <i class="fa fa-percent"></i> </li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Time - {{ $p->time }} times </li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Compound - <span class="aaaa">{{ $p->compound->name }}</span></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow: hidden">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon icon-left delete_button"
                                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DelModal"
                                                            data-id="{{ $p->id }}">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Invest Under This Package
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
```

But i suggest not to use `foreach` as you already know you need to show only plan id 3 . Try this :

```
        <div class="row">

     <?php $p = $plan["your_desired_id"]; ?> // means 2 or 3 .. whatever your desired id

     <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
      <div class="panel panel-info panel-pricing">
     <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>{{ $p->name }}</b></h3>
                                            </div>
    <div style="font-size: 18px;padding: 18px;" class="panel-body text-center">
     <p><strong>{{ $p->minimum }} {{ $basic->currency }} - {{ $p->maximum }} {{ $basic->currency }}</strong></p>
                                            </div>
 <ul style='font-size: 15px;' class="list-group text-center bold">
    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Commission - {{ $p->percent }} <i class="fa fa-percent"></i> </li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Time - {{ $p->time }} times </li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Compound - <span class="aaaa">{{ $p->compound->name }}</span></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow: hidden">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon icon-left delete_button"
                                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DelModal"
                                                            data-id="{{ $p->id }}">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Invest Under This Package
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find out a single value of plan from the collection . 
You can just find it by it's plan id

```
$plan = Plan::find(3);
```

Write this in your controller and then pass it down to your view blade file by using with.

Example :

```
return view("blade file name")->with(['plan'=>$plan])
```

Later in your blade file just access it's fields.

```
{{$plan->field_name}}
```